# CSS styles for arranging DIVs

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have several DIV which I want to arrange as shown here [Div Layout design](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6mc2po14wvibyrn/Chart_Layout.png)

Below is the HTML that I tried to achieve layout using CSS:

```
<body>
<div class="page">

<div>

        <div style="margin: 2px 0 2px 0px; text-align: center; font-size: large">
            <span>Chart Title</span>
        </div>

        <div style="float: left;display:block;">
            <span>Y-Axis Title</span>
        </div>


        <div id="Chart1">
        <!--Chart would be displayed here-->
        </div>

        <div style="clear:both; margin: 2px 0 2px 0px; text-align: center; ">
            <span>X-Axis Title</span>
        </div>

</div>

</div>
```

Can anyone help me out in CSS to achive the layour mentioned in image ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using a JavaScript chart? http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic

Comment: Not really a question, just you wanting us to do your work for you. Do you have a specific issue?

Comment: Google is your friend: http://speckyboy.com/2009/02/04/16-usable-css-graph-and-bar-chart-tutorials-and-techniques/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added some more styles, check it

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="page">

<div>

        <div style="margin: 2px 0 2px 0px; text-align: center; font-size: large; width:100%;display:block;">
            <span>Chart Title</span>
        </div>

        <div style="float: left;display:block;height:400px; width:19%;">
            <span>Y-Axis Title</span>
        </div>


        <div id="Chart1" style="flot:left;display:block; height:400px; width:100%;">
        Chart would be displayed here
        </div>

        <div style="clear:both; margin: 2px 0 2px 0px; text-align: center;display:block;  width:100%;">
            <span>X-Axis Title</span>
        </div>

</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Screen shot of your edited code]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a problem with `position: absolute` then this should work:

```
#Chart1, .chart-title, y-title, x-title {
  position: absolute;
}

.chart-title {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.x-title {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.y-title {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: auto 0;
}

#Chart1 {
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  right: 0;
}
```

That gives you the div layout. For y-title's vertical text you might want to do some kind of transformation. You of course have to name your divs with the appropriate classes

Comment: Thanks for CSS. But I need everything relative not absolute positions. I am working on a Asp.net MVC project. I have a DIV which includes all DIVs for titles and Chart. Secondly I have multiple charts, which I am rendering in a for loop.

Comment: You can have a relatively positioned div with fixed dimensions and have the content positioned absolutely within. And absolute doesn't rule out dynamic rendering. Just my 5c